# Getting serializable extras from Intent producing blank screen for few seconds

Tags: java, android, android-intent, fragment

I want to move from my Splash Screen Activity to Main Activity. In Splash Screen Activity, I'm fetching data from Firebase and store it in ArrayList. After that, I use extras to passing the data to my MainActivity. But, when the activity changes, it shows blank screen for around 3 seconds before the MainActivity started. When I remove my code for getting the bundle from the extras, the Intent works perfectly fine.

SplashActivity.java

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);                                      
        intent.putExtra("itemList", (Serializable) arrayList);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```

MainActivity.java (I passed the bundle to fragments)

```
        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        homeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, homeFragment, "home").commit();
```

HomeFragment.java

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        arrayList = new ArrayList();
        arrayList = (List<ItemModel>) getArguments().getSerializable("itemList");

        return view;
    }
```

I wonder why would that happen. Is it possible that the data I'm passing are too big (I tried to pass and get the smaller data and it works fine) or something and how should I solve it? Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do not fetch data while creating views i,e: `onCreateView(...)`

Correct way:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }
```

override `onViewCreated(...)` and fetch data inside this method

```
 arrayList = new ArrayList();
        arrayList = (List<ItemModel>) getArguments().getSerializable("itemList");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! But sadly, it doesn't work. I'm still getting the blank activity before the activity changes.